# jquery datepicker getdate format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have two problems in this code using jquery datepicker (first is alert the getdate method with time but I need the date only in format(yyyy-mm-dd)) the second problem I need to get the selected date into the textbox but it gives me error

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datepick.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.plugin.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#popupDatepicker').datepick({
dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
onSelect: function(){
var fullDate = $('#popupDatepicker').datepick('getDate');   
document.getElementByID('maach_year').value=fullDate;             
alert (fullDate);
}
});
});
</script>
<form action='".$server['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
<table>
<tr><td>Birth Date:</td><td><input type='date' id='popupDatepicker' size='15'     name='birth_day'></td>
 <td>Retirement Date:</td><td><input type='text' size='15' id='maach_year'  name='maach_year' ></td></tr> 
<input type='submit'/><br>
</table> 
</form>
```

I want also if I can add 65 to years that user select in the birth date, put it in the retirement textbox
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Though it's not required, providing a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo of the problem will help get your question answered quicker.

Comment: I try jsfiddle.net but I have problem in using this web site(because I'm beginner) for example jquery date picker not working for me and how to publish your code to website and get help. Thankyou very much for this website

Answer (score 27):

The DatePicker object has a [handy-dandy built-in date formatter](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate), and since it's a utility function, it doesn't even require you to apply a DatePicker to an element.

```
var date = new Date();
console.log($.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date));
```

or if you need the date of a DatePicker:

```
var date = $("#selector").datepicker("getDate");
console.log($.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the function [getDate()](http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html#getDate) returns a date object, not a string. You can format the date using [formatDate()](http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html#formatDate)

```
$('#maach_year').val($.datepick.formatDate('yyyy-mm-dd', fullDate));
```

If you want to add 65 years then

```
fullDate.setFullYear(fullDate.getFullYear() + 65)
```

Comment: I try the first one (maach_year) but not give me the value in it. Also the second code give me this error {TypeError: fullDate.getFullYear is not a function}

Comment: 'yyyy' returns something like 20192019

Comment: There are two issues in your response. datepick will return undefined. The date format is not correct. returning the year input doubled. You should check your answer output before posting it.